# Back of broken wooden chair

Tags: wood

Can you please advise the best steps to fix this chair?[two edges are cracked

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange. There are numerous previous Q&As here on repairs to furniture which will give you some of the generic info needed to approach a repair of this sort, so they're worth searching for and reading. The info will include some of the tools you may need (two or more clamps are useful to absolutely vital) and which glues you can select from, which have a bearing on how firmly you need to squeeze the parts together — some glues *require* heavy clamp pressure to produce their strongest bond (which you want here for peace of mind and safety).

Comment: Check out the answer in [this post](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/11080/should-i-further-break-split-wood-before-gluing/11081#11081) which discusses how to get the glue into the crack adequately. If this piece is important, you may want to consider a professional furniture woodworker to make the repair.